# Issue when rotating an object through the atan2 method

Tags: java, atan2

I'm trying to have an image follow my cursor, smoothly moving where it is located and turning to face it.

When i'm near the origin, it works flawlessy: the image will flip completely without issues, however the further i go from the origin of the window, the less the image turns. When i'm at the other side of the screen, instead of flipping over it'll rotate 5°-15° instead.

I'd love if somebody could point out what the issue is =)

Here's my current code for the image:

```
lblRover = new JLabel(sees) { // sees is an ImageIcon
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
            Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
            double x = getWidth()/2.0;
            double y = getHeight()/2.0;
            aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), x, y);
            g2.setTransform(aT);
            g2.setClip(oldshape);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    };
    lblRover.setSize(179, 180);
    lblRover.setLocation(500, 300);
    JFrame.getFrames()[0].add(lblRover);
```

And this is the code that handles the rotation, plus its movement:

```
        NewJFrame.PInf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        /* The frame is contained in NewJFrame, PInf is a PointerInfo */
        p = (NewJFrame.PInf.getLocation()); // p is a point
        p.x-=NewJFrame.getWindows()[0].getLocationOnScreen().x;
        p.y-=NewJFrame.getWindows()[0].getLocationOnScreen().y;
        //i subtract the location of the window relative to the screen
        img = NewJFrame.lblRover.getLocation();
        img.x+=NewJFrame.lblRover.getWidth()/2;
        img.y+=NewJFrame.lblRover.getHeight()/2;
        // img will be the point with the center of my image

        sas=getAngle(p,img); // sas is a float variable
        NewJFrame.degrees=sas;
        //
        // From now on i move the image
        //
        diffx = p.x-img.x;
        diffy = p.y-img.y;
        diffx/=80; // 80 is an arbitrary number to smooth the effect
        diffy/=80; // high numbers will make the image not move at all
        Point var = new Point(NewJFrame.lblRover.getLocation());
        // I may have to use img here or subtract width and height /2
        var.x+=diffx;
        var.y+=diffy;
        NewJFrame.lblRover.setLocation(var);

        // A 5ms sleep to smooth the movement
        // I also refresh a debug label
        // Also i do refresh the frame, otherwise nothing happens

        NewJFrame.jLabel1.setText(""+NewJFrame.lblRover.getLocation().y 
        +"/"+ p.y+" "+NewJFrame.lblRover.getLocation().x +"/"+ p.x );

        NewJFrame.getFrames()[0].repaint();
        try {
            sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(thread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after multiple tries i've narrowed it down.

Now, the rotation code is put last, before the repaint, and it looks like this:

```
sas=this.getAngle((float)diffy,(float)diffx);
NewJFrame.degrees=sas;
```

I've also created this new method that uses two float instead of two points:

```
public float getAngle(Float x, Float y) {
float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
//System.out.println(angle);
return angle;
```

I have no clue why it works now but it didn't before as the procedure is basically identical...but hey it works! =D